# Vue packages version mismatch

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to deploy my old nuxt project again with new changes but I get this error even tho I removed the node_modules folder, package-lock.json & refreshed the npm cache and of course run `npm i` after all of this + I don't have neither of these packages in my package.json.

Here's the error I'm getting after running `npm run dev`:

```
Vue packages version mismatch:
  
  - vue@3.2.45
  - vue-server-renderer@2.7.14
  
  This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
```

here's my package.json:

```
├── @nuxtjs/axios@5.13.6
├── @nuxtjs/dotenv@1.4.1
├── @nuxtjs/vercel-builder@0.22.1
├── @nuxtjs/vuetify@1.12.3
├── @stripe/stripe-js@1.46.0
├── body-parser@1.20.1
├── cookie-parser@1.4.6
├── cookieparser@0.1.0
├── core-js@3.26.1
├── cors@2.8.5
├── express@4.18.2
├── gsap@npm:@gsap/shockingly@3.11.3
├── nuxt-gsap-module@1.7.2
├── nuxt@2.15.8
├── stripe@8.222.0
├── underscore@1.13.6
└── vuex-persistedstate@4.1.0
```

I have tried all I can but cannot come up with a solution. Is there anything I could try to make this work?

Comment: In your lockfile, you may look for `vue@3.2.45`, there is a dependency that is aimed at being used only by Vue3 (and not Vue2/Nuxt2). PS: `@nuxtjs/dotenv` is not needed with Nuxt, it's baked-in. Also, give a try to those [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nuxt+mismatch+vue-server-renderer). The problem is still the one I mentioned. :)

Comment: I tried everything I could find in those questions :( still no success

Comment: I went through all the packages in my package.json and installed them one by one back and the app started working magically

Answer (score 0):

Please execute this command.

```
npm install vue@2.7.14 --save
```

Comment: This will not help.

Comment: Any solutions?  I am stuck in same problem vue@3.2.45 and vue-server-renderer@2.7.14

Comment: @Giampy71 check [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74783576/vue-packages-version-mismatch/74815974?noredirect=1#comment131983076_74783576)?